# Get error mpdf on hosting in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, php-curl

ErrorException: curl_exec() has been disabled for security reasons in /var/www/vhosts/phumcareermatching.com/httpdocs/www/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php:11927

Comment: And what is your question? The error message is pretty clear

Answer (score 1):

`curl_exec` was disabled on your hosting, exactly as the error message says.

The used `disable_functions` directive can be changed only in the global php.ini file, which will most likely not be possible on a shared hosting.

You could ask the hosting support to allow it, but I guess they have their reasons to disable it, so they will be reluctant to do so.

Answer (score 0):

first check if the curl is working properly. Open your `php.ini` file and check for `disable_functions` over there. And see whether your `curl_init` is packed there or not!